# Which cloud providers can be used for the simulation of DDoS attacks?

Tags: legal, denial-of-service, cloud-computing

Cloud providers have a great infrastructure to perform DDoS simulations. You can get thousands of virtual machines with different IP addresses, fully customizable with the tools you need for testing. But as far as my research is concerned, most of them do not allow DDoS testing and explicitly forbid it in their ToS. Amazon for example states:

> "You are prohibited from utilizing any tools or services in a manner
>   that perform Denial-of-Service (DoS) attacks, or simulations of such,
>   to or from ANY AWS asset, yours or otherwise."

Is there an established cloud provider that allows DDoS simulation and can be recommended for DDoS testing?

Comment: Thought exercise: pretend you're an established cloud provider, and do a risk analysis on letting anyone do anything even slightly resembling a DDOS using your resources.

Comment: VtC'ed this, as it's asking for product recommendations, which are explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: Try https://www.blitz.io/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest that the point here is terminology.  Whilst an illegal attempt to DDoS a site is obviously out of ToS for most cloud providers, what about providing load testing facilities?  when it comes down to it load testing to failure is likely to be pretty similar to DDoS and is, I would expect, quite legitimate. The key difference is authorisation.  DDoS is an unauthorised attack and load testing is a legitimate activity that a company has authorised.

There are a number of cloud based load testing companies (I'll avoid listing them otherwise this could be a product recommendation) but also AWS can likely be used for load testing (e.g. [bees with machine guns](http://blog.apps.chicagotribune.com/2010/07/08/bees-with-machine-guns/))